Why does this system of trigonometric equations have no solution?
Clear["`*"]
Reduce[{Sin[x] + Sin[3 x] + Sin[5 x] == 1, 
  Cos[x] + Cos[3 x] + Cos[5 x] == Sqrt[2] + 1, 
  tan3x == Sin[3 x]/Cos[3 x]}, tan3x, {x}, Reals]

How can this trigonometric equation have no solution?
This is how it works by hand：
Given the equations:
$$\sin x + \sin 3x + \sin 5x = 1,$$
$$\cos x + \cos 3x + \cos 5x = \sqrt{2} + 1,$$
we are asked to find the value of $\tan 3x$.
Firstly, let's use the sum-to-product formulas for sine and cosine:
For sine:
$$\sin A + \sin B = 2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right),$$
For cosine:
$$\cos A + \cos B = 2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right).$$
Applying these to our equations, we get:
For the first equation:
$$\sin x + \sin 5x = 2\sin\left(\frac{x+5x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-5x}{2}\right) = 2\sin(3x)\cos(-2x) = 2\sin(3x)\cos(2x),$$
and thus:
$$2\sin(3x)\cos(2x) + \sin 3x = 1.$$
For the second equation:
$$\cos x + \cos 5x = 2\cos\left(\frac{x+5x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-5x}{2}\right) = 2\cos(3x)\cos(-2x) = 2\cos(3x)\cos(2x),$$
and thus:
$$2\cos(3x)\cos(2x) + \cos 3x = \sqrt{2} + 1.$$
Now we solve for $\sin(3x)$ and $\cos(3x)$:
From the first equation:
$$2\sin(3x)\cos(2x) + \sin 3x = 1,$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1) = 1.$$
From the second equation:
$$2\cos(3x)\cos(2x) + \cos 3x = \sqrt{2} + 1,$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1) = \sqrt{2} + 1.$$
Dividing the two equations to eliminate $\cos(2x)$, we get:
$$\frac{\sin 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1)}{\cos 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1},$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1},$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan 3x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1}.$$
To rationalize the denominator, we multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate $(\sqrt{2} - 1)$:
$$\tan 3x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1},$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan 3x = \sqrt{2} - 1.$$

@minhthien_2016 There is no error in the method.For example, solving this equation can be calculated:Reduce[{Tan[2 x] == 2 Sqrt[2], tanx == Sin[x]/Cos[x]}, tanx, {x}]get the result:tanx == 1/Sqrt[2] || tanx == -Sqrt[2]

There is no common solution for  Sin[x] + Sin[3 x] + Sin[5 x] == 1 and for Cos[x] + Cos[3 x] + Cos[5 x] == Sqrt[2] + 1.   That's all.  Your derivations are incorrect.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

FunctionPeriod[Sin[x] + Sin[3  x] + Sin[5  x], x]

(* 2 π *)

sol1 = Solve[{Sin[x] + Sin[3  x] + Sin[5  x] == 1, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]


FunctionPeriod[Cos[x] + Cos[3  x] + Cos[5  x], x]

(* 2 π *)

sol2 = Solve[{Cos[x] + Cos[3  x] + Cos[5  x] == Sqrt[2] + 1, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, 
  x]


NumberLinePlot[{x /. sol1, x /. sol2}]


There is no alignment of the solutions, the first two equations cannot both be satisfied.
Solve[{Sin[x] + Sin[3  x] + Sin[5  x] == 1,
  Cos[x] + Cos[3  x] + Cos[5  x] == Sqrt[2] + 1,
  0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]

(* {} *)

Reduce[{Sin[x] + Sin[3  x] + Sin[5  x] == 1,
  Cos[x] + Cos[3  x] + Cos[5  x] == Sqrt[2] + 1,
  0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]

(* False *)


Wonderful demonstration. +1 :)

Just a variant of @BobHanlon excellent answer illustrating there is no solution:
f[x_] := Sin[x] + Sin[3 x] + Sin[5 x];
g[x_] := Cos[x] + Cos[3 x] + Cos[5 x];
e1 = x /. NSolve[f[x] - 1 == 0 && 0 < x < 2 Pi, x];
e2 = x /. NSolve[g[x] == Sqrt[2] + 1 && 0 < x < 2 Pi, x];
dir1 = {#, Directive[Red]} & /@ e1;
dir2 = {#, Directive[Blue]} & /@ e2;
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 GridLines -> {dir1~Join~dir2, {1, Sqrt[2] + 1}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[{#, f@#}] & /@ e1, Blue, 
   Point[{#, g@#}] & /@ e2}]


